# Retrieving Random Rows from Table Using NEWID()

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a sql query and i am using `distinct` statement

```
   CREATE proc SProc_SelectPhotographersByLocation         
@locationID varchar(500)          
as            
begin          


DECLARE @TEST varchar(1000)          
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(1000)          

SET @TEST = @locationID          

SET @SQLQuery = 'select distinct ContributerSubCategoryMapping.ContributorID,  PhotographerContributors_tbl.*  from ContributerSubCategoryMapping               
  left outer join PhotographerContributors_tbl on PhotographerContributors_tbl.ContributorId=ContributerSubCategoryMapping.ContributorID              
  left outer join tbl_City on tbl_City.CityID=PhotographerContributors_tbl.Location              
  where         
  PhotographerContributors_tbl.Location IN('+ @locationID +') and PhotographerContributors_tbl.IsActive=''1'' order by Newid()'          
EXECUTE(@SQLQuery)          

end
```

i am getting error on the query when i use `NEWID()` on that query.
Error is

> **ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified**.

please help me for this issue

Comment: **1.** This is SQL Server syntax, not MySQL, I think your tags are incorrect. **2.** `NEWID()` does not appear in this query, you should post the query that actually causes the error. **3.** The error message seems fairly self explanatory, you cannot use distinct, and order by NEWID() without also selecting `NEWID()`, which will make the distinct meaningless, instead move your query into a subquery with select distinct, then order this subquery by `NEWID()`. **4.** Why are you even ordering by `NEWID()`

Comment: thanks for the reply. actually i am getting randomly data from this query if i am not using order by newid() it's executed perfectly.is there another way to select randomly  data from this query please help

Comment: As an aside: read up about SQL injection https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: What *should* your query return? Why is the DISTINCT in there anyway?

Comment: in the ContributerSubCategoryMapping table the ContributorID is repeated rows

Comment: Not within the scope of the question but I would really advise against this dynamic SQL approach. If you are using SQL Server 2008 or later use [table valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `group by` instead of `distinct`.  One way is by listing the columns explicitly:

```
select csm.ContributorID, pc.col1, pc.col2, . . .
from ContributerSubCategoryMapping csm left outer join
     PhotographerContributors_tbl pc
     on pc.ContributorId = csm.ContributorID left outer join
     tbl_City c
     on c.CityID = pc.Location              
where pc.Location IN ('+ @locationID +') and pc.IsActive=''1''
group by csm.ConstributorId, pc.col1, pc.col2, . . .
order by Newid();
```

However, I don't understand the query.  The tables `ContributerSubCategoryMapping` and `tbl_City` don't seem to be being used.  So why not just do this?

```
select pc.*
from PhotographerContributors_tbl pc
where pc.Location IN ('+ @locationID +') and pc.IsActive=''1''
order by Newid();
```

Comment: I like this suggestion. I have reached my daily vote limit - otherwise I would have upvoted it.

Comment: Yep, sums up all my thoughts, why use 2 joins when you can use none... Also to add to *"One way is by listing the columns explicitly"* - [Should be doing this anyway](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)